# In a C# project, how can I refer to a project written in C++ and compiled with /clr?

Tags: c++, dll

I have a fairly large project written in unmanaged C++ and generating a DLL.  I would like to be able to use the DLL in a .Net project (in this case, just a bare-bones WinForm application).  I rebuilt the DLL with /clr set.  It built successfully.  In my WinForm project, I selected Add Reference, selected the Project tab, and selected the DLL project.  It was successfully added as a reference in my WinForm project.  However, I am having trouble using the DLL.  I want to add a using directive for it, but I do not know what name the DLL has.  I tried using the same name as the file, but it didn't work.  How do I find out what its name is for use in a using directive?

Thanks very much!

RobR

Comment: I obviously left something out.  I added the DLL reference to my WinForms project by browsing to the DLL file.  When I double-click on the reference, my ObjectBrowser window opens.  The DLL object is shown with an interface symbol, the same way System is.  But System can be expanded, and of course it's got tons of things listed under it.  My DLL cannot be expanded, and doesn't seem to have anything in it.  What step did I leave out?

Comment: Forgetting to add `ref class` to your source code?  Forgetting to make them public?  We can't see your screen from here, you do have to describe it in *words*.  Create a "hello world" version from the class library project template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/clr` switch enables you to mix .NET types (`ref class`, `interface class`) with the other C++ code.  It doesn't magically make native C++ code usable from C#.

Among other reasons, C++ code heavily relies on object addresses remaining constant, but in .NET they do not.  .NET requires that all objects have a v-table so that the garbage collector can find out what data type the object is (and therefore where within the object pointers are contained) but most native types have no v-table at all.  The compiler can't make native types .NET-compatible without changing the layout and breaking compatibility with native code.  Which would defeat the purpose.  So while the compiler can generate metadata for the native types, it's not useful to C#.  Instead it lets you include .NET-compatible classes and native types together in the same DLL and internally call between them seamlessly.

To answer your other question "How can I find out what namespaces are defined within an arbitrary .NET assembly?" use an assembly viewer/decompiler such as dotPeek, .NET Reflector, etc.

Comment: Sigh.  There's no magic.  Not surprising.  I've seen suggestions to use P/Invoke or to wrap it in an ActiveX executable and use COM Interop.  Will either of those work?

Comment: P/Invoke won't since your C++ code is in the form of classes.  It's only good for free functions with primitive parameter types.  COM aka DCOM aka ActiveX is the way native code shares functionality at the class level, and .NET plays that game too.  But reworking your native code into COM objects is likely even more work than conversion (or wrapper) to `ref class`.  So I'd only go the COM route if you'll have other native consumers as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write managed wrapper classes in C++. Check [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235281.aspx).

Actually you dont need to compile the entire dll as /clr, only the managed wrappers. Not all c++ code works with /clr and there is a modarate slowdown.